# How to include the Vuetify2 library only once?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have many of my libraries and they all use VUE 2 and VUETIFY 2, how do I include them only once in the parent component? I want to reduce the size of the included libraries.

Example vue.config of one of the libraries

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
const { VuetifyLoaderPlugin } = require('vuetify-loader')
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: ['vuetify'],
  css: {
    extract: false,
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    externals: /^vuetify\//,
    plugins: [
      new VuetifyLoaderPlugin(),
      new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
        analyzerMode: 'static',
        openAnalyzer: false,
      }),
    ],
```

Using "externals" I excluded VUETIFY from the build. How can I pass it from the parent to the child components?